# How can i set background image to row column in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set a background image to row column in bootstrap, but for some reason it's not working, the `index.html` file and the image are in the root dir, I searched a lot in google but I didn't find solution, please help, and thanks in advance

index.html code

```
<div class="row main_row">
        <div class="col-md-2 left_menu">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Employee ID:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 right_menu">
         123
        </div>
    </div>
```

css code:

```
.right_menu{
    background: url('background_image1.jpg') no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
   -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
   -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Its working here https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/380/

Comment: Where in the file system is your CSS file?

Comment: thanks i found the issue, need to add '../' before image name, cause the css code not in the same path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image path should be relative to your `.css` file. So, for example, if your CSS file is in a folder `/css/styles.css` and your image is in the root folder (`/background_image1.jpg`), you should set the background url to:

```
background: url('../background_image1.jpg') no-repeat;
```